How to validate SQLAlchemy session.execute(stmt).scalars().all() result using by Pydantic model
@router.get("/get_in_list/", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, response_model=LanguageModelResponse)
async def get_language_list(
    label: Optional[str],
    session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db),
) -> List[LanguageModelResponse]:
    
    """
    Получение списка языков(фильтр по label)

    """
    stmt = select(LanguageModel)

    if label is not None:
        stmt = stmt.where(LanguageModel.label.ilike(f"%{label}%"))

    query =  (await session.execute(stmt)).scalars().all()
    print('asdasd', type(query))

    return [LanguageModelResponse.model_validate(row) for row in query]

When i try validate query im getting error: {'type': 'model_attributes_type', 'loc': ('response',), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from', 'input': [LanguageModelResponse(id=329135526940508160, label='Yakut',  code='ykt'), LanguageModelResponse(id=329135526940508161, label='Turkish', code='trk')], 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_attributes_type'}
Solution it is to convert query result to dict but i dont know how to do this
Im already tried mapping().all() methods

You've defined your response model as a single entry in the decorator, not as a list: response_model=LanguageModelResponse - you can drop this override, since you have already used the correct type as the returned type from the function

Yeap, im feel so blind, thx!
